# How to find instances in an unlabeled dataset, that are most promising to be informative when building a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-mining, text-mining

My problem is that I have a large unlabeled dataset, but over time I want it to become labeled and build a confident classifier.

This can be done by active learning, but active learning needs an initial classifier to be built for it to then estimate and rank the remaining unlabeled instances by how informative they are expected to be to the classifier.

To build the initial classifier, I need to label some examples by hand. my questions is: Are there methods to find likely informative examples in the initial unlabeled dataset, without the help of an initial classifier?

I thought about just using k-means with some number of clusters, run it and label one example from each cluster, then train the classifier on these.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to disagree with Edward Raff.

k-means may turn out to be useful here (if your data is continuous).

Just use a rather large value of k.

The idea is to avoid picking too similar objects, but get a sample that covers the data reasonably well. k-means may fail to "cluster" complex data, but it works reasonably well for *quantization*. So it will return a "less random, more representative" sample from your data.

But beware: *k-means centers do not correspond to data points*. You could either use a medoid based algorithm, or just find the closes instance to each center.

Some alternatives:

- if you can afford to label "a" objects, run k-means with k=a
- run k-means with k=5*a, and select 20% of the centers (maybe preferring those with highest density)
- choose 0.5*a by k-means, 0.5*a randomly
- do either, but choose only 0.5*a objects to label. Train a classifier, find the 0.5*a unlabeled objects that the classifier had the lowest confidence on

Answer (score 0):

No. If you don't have *any* labeled data, you have no way of determining which points are the most informative. k-means does not necessarily help either, as you don't know where the decision surface lives.

You are overthinking the problem. Just randomly sample some data and get it labeled. Once you have a few hundred - thousand points labeled you can start to look at the labeled data and makes some decisions about where to head next.

Comment: I disagree. I believe a k-means based sample can help locate the decision boundaries faster.

Comment: I don't mean to say k-means *won't* help. I can see situations where it would help and situations where it would hurt. I just think the difference is so minute it's really not worth worrying about - the time is better spent getting some code set up to make labeling faster & easier, and getting some labels. Once you have a few hundred points labeled you can move to much smarter active learning methods.